# CorePlot errors in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, core-plot, xcode7.3

When I upgrade Xcode to version 7.3 and compile my project, it comes many errors.

The project could be compiled normally before I upgrade the Xcode.

Please tell me how to fix it? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to a newer version of Core Plot. Download [release 2.1](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/releases/tag/release_2.1) or pull the latest code from GitHub.